# Django model Diamond multiple inheritance

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, model

I'm a web programming starter.
I'm doing web programming with Django.
I found a problem with modeling.
Below is my code.
(I wrote this in Python 2.7.12.)

```
class ImageModel(models.Model):
    pass

class FaceModel(ImageModel):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "FaceModel"
        super(FaceModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do Something
        super(FaceModel, self).save()

class ObjectModel(ImageModel):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "ObjectModel"
        super(ObjectModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do Something
        super(ObjectModel, self).save()

class PlaceModel(ImageModel):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "PlaceModel"
        super(PlaceModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do Something
        super(PlaceModel, self).save()

class AllModel(FaceModel, ObjectModel, PlaceModel):
    pass
```

But, The result is the value I want. But there is one problem. FaceModel.save() call one, ObjectModel.save() call two and PlaceModel.save() call four times. It's too slow. I want to call the save() function each model only once. What should I do?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this kind of inheritance? Generally non-abstract model inheritance in Django models is to be avoided; I've never seen anyone try to inherit like this.

Comment: Because, I create a website that extracts images through a deep-running model. I will have a total of three models, faces, places and object recognition. I also need a model that integrates these models and runs the above three at once. So I thought of the above model structure. Is there a better model structure, or is there a way that I think?

Comment: Have a look at model proxies (link at end), they are good for this sort of thing.
http://benlopatin.com/using-django-proxy-models/